# materialize cant set data-error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, materialize

Im trying to use a library called jquery validate which just takes form inputs and returns success or error messages. With materialize I can use the data-error and data-success. I cant get the error working at all. I see it changes in the console but not on the webpage. Until I click off an input the go back to an input i know is wrong then it gives me an error warning
Even then the error is not persistent it disappears when i click onto another input again.
I can see by watching the inspector a valid class appears in the input.
I will post my code below any explanations why this happens would be appreciated:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#signup_form").validate({
    rules: {
      first_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
      last_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
      user_name: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 3
      }
    },
    //For custom messages
    messages: {
      first_name: {
        required: "Enter your first name",
        text: true,
        minlength: "Enter at least 2 characters"
      },
      last_name: {
        required: "Enter your second name",
        text: true,
        minlength: "Enter at least 2 characters"
      },
      user_name: {
        required: "Enter a username",
        maxlength: "Enter at least 3 characters"
      }
    },
    errorClass: 'invalid',
    validClass: "valid",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      $(element)
        .closest("form")
        .find("label[for='" + element.attr("id") + "']")
        .attr('data-error', error.text());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<form id="signup_form" class="col s6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input id="user_name" type="text" name="user_name" class="validate">
      <label for="user_name" data-error="" data-success="">User Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Too see the error start typing the click off the input and back on the type another letter its weird

Comment: Your rule makes no sense... you've set `maxlength: 3`, but your message says "enter at least 3 characters".   "MAX 3" means "no more than 3".

Comment: its a string on maxLength, it doesnt need too make sense. max length is just a test to see if it works. I forgot to change the text my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase someone comes across this in the future I wont take it down. Look through your inputs and remove the class 'validate'. 
I'm not entirely sure but what I think happens is the `validate` class is looking at the input and testing for any of the markup contstraints i.e. max, min, step, type etc. This will add the `valid` class to all inputs regardless of the rules set in `validate()` because it fulfils the requirements made in markup.
So when we remove the `validate` class the validate library can act accordingly.

Comment: Can you make this a better answer by explaining why this is the problem?